# Как прочитать страницу по протоколу HTTPS

Tags: c#, https

Как будет правильно?

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://10.220.83.1:4848") as HttpWebRequest;
request.AuthenticationLevel = AuthenticationLevel.None;
CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
request.CookieContainer = cookies;
NetworkCredential myCred = new NetworkCredential("", "", "");
CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache();
myCache.Add(new Uri("https://10.220.83.1:4848"), "Basic", myCred);
request.Credentials = myCache;
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/webclient

Comment: там ничего не сказано про протокол httpS, а мне нужен именно он, как прочитать по http я знаю.

Comment: а в чем разницы то?...ssl вам сертификат нужно подключить, все остальное вроде также должно быть
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560804/how-do-i-use-webrequest-to-access-an-ssl-encrypted-site-using-https

Comment: а откуда его взять если сайт примера https://www.google.ru

Answer (score 1):

Дело было в самоподписанности сертификата. С доверенным сертификатом проблем нет никаких. Пример для самоподписанныз сертификатов:

```
public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(
object sender,
X509Certificate certificate,
X509Chain chain,
SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) {
return true; 
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://ваш адрес") as HttpWebRequest;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ValidateServerCertificate;
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
}
```